# How to finish this integration?

Tags: integration

I'm working with the integral below, but not sure how to finish it...

$$\int \frac{3x^3}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+1}}\,dx = \int \frac{3x^3}{\sqrt[3]{A}}\cdot \frac{dA}{4x^3} = \frac{3}{4} \int \frac{dA}{\sqrt[3]{A}} = \frac{3}{4}\cdot\quad???$$
where $A=x^4+1$ and so $dA=4x^3\,dx$

Comment: Please write the problem using MathJax instead of posting (a very low quality) photo.

Comment: Sorry, I am just rewriting it.

Comment: **HINT :** Let $u=x^4+1$ and $du=4x^3\ dx$, then
$$
\int\frac{3x^3}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+1}}\ dx=\frac34\int\ u^{\Large-\frac13}\ du.
$$

Comment: Thank you Bill, you were faster

Comment: No problem. Hopefully I interpreted correctly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I interpreted your **very** low quality picture correctly...

You got a good start on the problem. That's the right substitution. Rewrite...

$$\frac{3}{4} \int \frac{dA}{\sqrt[3]{A}} = \frac{3}{4} \int A^{-1/3}\,dA$$

...and use the backwards power rule...

$$ = \frac{3}{4} \frac{A^{2/3}}{2/3} +C = \cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[\large 3]{A}} = \dfrac 1{A^{1/3}} = A^{-1/3}$$

Now use the power rule.

$$ \frac{3}{4} \int A^{-1/3}\,dA = \frac 34 \dfrac {A^{2/3}}{\frac 23} + C = \dfrac 98 A^{2/3} + C$$